# Подсчет очков при выполнении функции

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать нужный мне функционал. Есть некие очки, которые должны подсчитываться при выполнении функции `void OnTapSuccess` (функция выполняется при тач-нажатии на экран). Очки должны считаться от 0 до 10. Из переменной куда будут записываться очки мне будет необходимо отнимать их (тратить).

```
int count = 0;

//Тап по экрану произошел
void OnTapSuccess(int fingerId, float heldTime)
{
    count++; //количество нажатий на экран
    Debug.Log("Tapped Count: " + count + "\r\n"
             + "Finger ID: " + fingerId + "\r\n"
             + "Held Time: " + heldTime);
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
    GameObject.Find("Pride").GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Click");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, и вам надо ограничить записываемые значения от 0 до 10, то преобразуйте свой счетчик из поля в свойство:

```
int count;

int Count
{
    get { return count; }
    set
    {
         count = value < 0 ? 0 : value > 10 ? 10 : value;
    }
}

//Тап по экрану произошел
void OnTapSuccess(int fingerId, float heldTime)
{
    Count++; //количество нажатий на экран
    Debug.Log("Tapped Count: " + Count + "\r\n"
             + "Finger ID: " + fingerId + "\r\n"
             + "Held Time: " + heldTime);
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + Count.ToString();
    GameObject.Find("Pride").GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Click");

}
```

Comment: Да все правильно, нужно было искусственно ограничить интовую переменную. Спасибо, ваше решение подошло.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно вот результат, в котором используется решение товарища @Mirdin
Не претендую на лаконичность кода)) все таки это первое что я делаю))

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.Collections;

    public class TouchCounter : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject[] obj;

        Text scoreText;

        int count = 0;

        int mana = 0;

        int Mana
        {
            get { return mana; }
            set
            {
                mana = value < 0 ? 0 : value > 10 ? 10 : value;
            }
        }

        void Start()
        {
            scoreText = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<Text>();
        }


        float[] fingerIdTimer = new float[5] { 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f }; //5 fingers max 
        bool[] fingerIdValid = new bool[5] { true, true, true, true, true }; //One determine invalid, must be rest in TouchPhase.Ended
        const float timeOut = 0.5f; //Anything more than 0 and less than timeOut value is tap

        void Update()
        {
            //Loop over all finger touching the screen
            for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
            {
                //Will only increment if finger is valid
                if (fingerIdValid[i])
                {
                    fingerIdTimer[i] += Time.deltaTime;
                }

                //If we reach the time out value and finger is still valid reset the finger id
                if (fingerIdTimer[i] > timeOut && fingerIdValid[i])
                {
                    fingerIdTimer[i] = 0f; //Reset Held Time
                    fingerIdValid[i] = false; //Invalid
                    OnTapFailed(i, fingerIdTimer[i]);
                }

                //After touch is released, Anything more than 0 and less than timerOut value is tap
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    if (fingerIdTimer[i] > 0 && fingerIdTimer[i] < timeOut)
                    {
                        OnTapSuccess(i, fingerIdTimer[i]);
                    }

                    fingerIdTimer[i] = 0f; //Reset Held Time when released
                    fingerIdValid[i] = true; //Reset Invalid when released
                }
            }
            switch (Mana) //ограничение до 10 нужно было тут
            {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    obj[1].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    obj[2].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    obj[3].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    obj[4].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    obj[5].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    obj[6].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    obj[7].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    obj[8].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    obj[9].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    obj[10].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);
                    break;
            }
        }


        //Tap was successful
        void OnTapSuccess(int fingerId, float heldTime)
        {

            count++; //Increment the tap count
            mana++; //инкремент Маны до 10
            Debug.Log("Tapped Count: " + count + "\r\n"
                     + "Finger ID: " + fingerId + "\r\n"
                     + "Held Time: " + heldTime);
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
            GameObject.Find("Pride").GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Click");

        }

        //Tap failed (Time out Occured)
        void OnTapFailed(int fingerId, float heldTime)
        {
              Debug.Log("Tap Failed: " + fingerId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Mirdin вот для чего все))